# Microsoft/SSRS report textbox returns #error when string value that is decimal is converted to decimal and empty string is just printed

Tags: .net, sql-server, excel, vba, reporting-services

I have a value that is coming back from a database as string, but it could be a `decimal` and when it is a `decimal` I want to display it as a `decimal` and format it a certain way, if it isn't a `decimal` then I just display whatever value comes back.

Here's my code:

```
=Iif
(
    IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value) Or Len(Trim(Fields!Amount.Value)) < 1, 
    Fields!Amount.Value, //have even tried to do CStr(Fields!Amount.Value) in case conversion below makes the report expect decimals for all values
    Iif
    (
        IsNumeric(Fields!Amount.Value), 
        CDec(Fields!Amount.Value),
        Fields!Amount.Value
    )
)
```

The comment above is not part of the code, I just put that here. Anyway, based on the above, all decimals are successfully converted to decimals and display ok, but all those strings that are either empty or hold a non-numeric value show up as #Error.

Here's a sample result display:

```
72.00
95.00
#Error
20.00
```

What's wrong with this expression? and why couldn't SSRS use c# instead of VB?!!?

**UPDATE:** I know that the problem has to do with the conversion and not the logic to check whether the value is nothing, less than 1 character, or a numeric, because the following works:

```
=Iif
(
    IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value) Or Len(Trim(Fields!Amount.Value)) < 1, 
    "is nothing or less than 1",
    Iif
    (
        IsNumeric(Fields!Amount.Value), 
        "is numeric",
        "is not numeric"
    )
)
```

this will correctly display:

```
is numeric
is numeric
is nothing or less than 1
is numeric
```

Comment: Why are not handling it in SQL? When it is decimal what is value database currently returning is 72 or 72.00 or 72.000000 or something else? All I see you are looking for empty value and length of that field less than 1. What happens if your dataset return "ABC"? Or is it not possible with your dataset to return "ABC"?

Comment: Long story short, the amount type in the db is varchar(20), dont ask me why. But since it CAN be a value other than a number, they want me to display...as I was writing this I just wondered why it is that I couldn't do it in SQL. I can't remember, so I think I'll do it there.

Comment: I always feel solving in SQL is much better, cleaner and easier. Try CASE WHEN or NULLIF. I have also edited my answer to show the SQL way.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal: Solving in SQL may mean undesirable mixing business and presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

`Iif` is a function and so all arguments are evaluated before the function is called. So there is no use in using Iif to prevent error.

I suppose you need a User defined function ([Writing Custom functions in SSRS](http://ateeqmirza.blogspot.cz/2010/07/writing-custom-functions-in-ssrs.html))

So instead `Iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Amount.Value),...)`

define a function

```
Function DecimalIfPossible(Value as string) As Object
  If IsNumeric(Fields!Amount.Value) then
      Return  CDec(Fields!Amount.Value)
   else
      Return  Fields!Amount.Value
   End if
End Function
```

and call it `DecimalIfPossible(Fields!Amount.Value)`.

Comment: This worked wonders for me except i changed it to Function DecimalIfPossible(byVal Value as string) As Object and passed in (Value) instead of fields!... and in the expression =code.DecimalIfPossible(Fields!field.value)

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert the decimal back to string

```
 IIF
    (
        IsNumeric(Fields!Amount.Value), 
        CStr(CDec(Fields!Amount.Value)),
        Fields!Amount.Value
    )
```

Based on your logic you are looking for empty or Null string, so handle it in SQL. Convert it to NULL if it is non numeric something like

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Amount) = 1 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END As Amount
```

or use `NULLIF`

Comment: This still gives the same #Error